# Loop Pomise on method object

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I got a list of Router (Liste_routeur_wifi) Object, with a Flash method, which initiate the flash of a new image, and return a promise when it's done.
I'm connecting to the router over Wifi so I can only do it one by one.

I give you a (working) example for 2 router on the list (index 0 and 1), but I would like to make it for N routers and I have no idea how.

If anyone could show me it would be very helpful.

```
wifi.connect({
              ssid: Liste_routeur_wifi[0].ssid,
               password: Liste_routeur_wifi[0].password
            }, async function(err) {
                if (err) {
                   console.log(err);
                } else {        
                     //If im connected
                     console.log('Connexion établie');
                     //flash method return a promise with the flashed router                            Liste_routeur_wifi[0].flash(browser).then(function(routeurflash0) {
                     console.log(routeurflash0);
                     //when the promise is complete, i wouldlike to go to the next router
                         wifi.connect({
                               ssid: Liste_routeur_wifi[1].ssid,
                               password: Liste_routeur_wifi[1].password
                             }, async function(err) {
                             if (err) {
                               console.log(err);
                             } else {
                               console.log('Connexion établie'); Liste_routeur_wifi[1].flash(browser).then(function(routeurflash1) {
                                                console.log(routeurflash1);

                              })

                          }
            });
```

Comment: Do not pass an `async function` as a callback.

Comment: What is `wifi.connect`? Doesn't it return a promise like `.flash()` does?

Comment: the callback isn't async anymore thanks you.
wifi.connect is provided by a node module 'node-wifi', i didn't want to re-code it?
.flash() is a method i wrote myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about recursion?

Maybe not 100% correct for your needs but

```
connectWifi(0, routerAmount);

function connectWifi(index, n){
    wifi.connect({
        ssid: Liste_routeur_wifi[index].ssid,
        password: Liste_routeur_wifi[index].password
    }, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('Connexion établie');

            Liste_routeur_wifi[index].flash(browser).then(function(routeurflash) {
                console.log(routeurflash);
                if(index <= n){
                    return connectWifi(index++, n);
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            })

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It worked, thank you , i should have think about it!

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options.

Providing you can do it in parallel you can use `Promise.all`

Providing you would like to do it one by one:

```
return Liste_routeur_wifi.reduce(
    (current, next) =>
      current
        .then(t => next.flash())
        .catch(err => {console.log(err);}),
    Promise.resolve(),
)
```